# How to find second element of a WebElement in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i want to get the second child element of content.When i try this code it says the nth-child(2) is not a valid expression. How can i get the child element of content?

```
 content= stream.find_elements_by_class_name("content")
        for l in content:
            child = l.find_elements_by_xpath("nth-child(2)")
            print(child.tag_name)
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the complete error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me.

```
child = l.find_elements_by_xpath("./*[2]").
```